# Sed remove lines in a bash script between braces

Tags: bash, sed

I am trying to remove comments and  blank lines in a script that has curly braces.
The below code works well when the file does not have braces but if it does have braces, then the code only removes comments and leaves blank spaces in its place.

```
sed  -e 's/#.*$//' -e '/^$/d' file >> file
```

the output results in the following without removing the blank lines

```
 more stuff above here




 location ~ \.php$ {
     root     /usr/share/nginx/html;
     fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
     fastcgi_index  index.php;
     fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
     include        fastcgi_params;
   }



 location ~ /\.ht {
     deny  all;
   }
 }
```

thanks

Comment: Have you tried `sed  -e 's/#.*$//' -e '/^[ \t]*$/d' file >> file`?

Comment: Your example works for me. Do you perhaps have DOS-style line endings?

Comment: thank you Axel.. yours also works perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your script work perfectly in zsh.
try this

```
sed  -e 's/^#//' -e '/^[ \t]*$/d'
```